# Storing data much bigger than RAM in SQLite

Tags: sql, database, sqlite

I have around 100 GB of stock market data in the following format:

```
datetime             open    high   low     close   volume
2014-10-02 15:34:00  18.39  18.50   18.32   18.41   5100
2014-10-02 15:35:00  18.41  18.49   18.41   18.49   200
2014-10-02 15:36:00  18.45  18.50   18.45   18.46   600
```

Each ticker has its own CSV file of data in the format above, so I am thinking of storing each ticker's data in its own table. There would be around 10,000 tickers, so 10,000 tables.

My question is whether I should have a single database of all these tables, or have a separate database for each ticker. My priority is speed of accessing the data.

I will only be making simple queries (i.e. `select * from TICKER where datetime > 2014-10-02 15:34:00`) to pull the data into Pandas, and will only be using data from one ticker at a time (I am looping over a list of tickers and doing some analysis on them individually). All of this will be done locally on a computer with 8 GB of RAM.

Comment: Time series databases like `InfluxDB`, `OpenTSDB` etc are made for these kind of scenarios. You might want to take a look at them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would store everything in one table.  There is more overhead than you might imagine in using a separate table for each ticker -- and queries and maintenance become a nightmare.  You can arrange your data using indexes, for faster access.

If performance on even slightly complex queries is an issue, you might want to consider a different database.